# How do I do a website health check using CURL command

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to monitor a website using curl but the output doesn't seem to work, please see commands below:

```
#!/bin/bash

varDate=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
varCurlError=$(curl -sSf https://website.com > /dev/null)
varHttpCode=$(curl -Is https://website.com | head -n 1)
varResponseTime=$(curl -s -w '%{time_total}' -o /dev/null website.com)
varOutput="$varDate | $varCurlError | $varHttpCode | $varResponseTime"
echo $varOutput
```

The output looks like this :

```
 | 0.07323 18:51:40 | | HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

What can I change or add to fix the output.

Much appreciated.

Comment: The header lines are terminated with `\r\n`, so you'll need to pipe curl output to `| tr -d '\r'`

Comment: The varCurlError=$(curl -sSf https://website.com > /dev/null) still shows nothing 2020-06-23 22:16:51 | XXX | HTTP/1.1 200 OK | 0.070. Marked it with the XXX.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
varDate=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
varCurlError=$(curl -sSf https://website.com  2>&1 >/dev/null)
varHttpCode=$(curl -Is https://website.com | head -n 1)
varResponseTime=$(curl -s -w '%{time_total}' -o /dev/null website.com | tr -d \\r )
varOutput="$varDate | $varCurlError | $varHttpCode | $varResponseTime"
echo $varOutput
```

There are two corrections:

1. tr -d \r was added as per glenn jackman.  The CR is causing your varResponseTime to be printed at the beginning of the line.  The `tr` command deletes the CR.
2. You need to first redirect stderr to stdout before you close file descriptor 1 in your varCurlError statement.  Now, errors reported by curl to stderr will be sent to stdout (and captured by your $() enclosure).  The output curl sends to stdout will go to the bitbucket.  **Order is important**.  `>/dev/null 2>&1` doesn't work - it sends stdout and stderr to /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

@glenn jackman is correct about the need to pipe the curl output to `| tr -d '\r'`
That is, change your code to

```
#!/bin/bash
varDate=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | tr -d '\r')
varCurlError=$(curl -sSf https://website.com | tr -d '\r' > /dev/null)
varHttpCode=$(curl -Is https://website.com | tr -d '\r' | head -n 1)
varResponseTime=$(curl -s -w '%{time_total}' -o /dev/null website.com | tr -d '\r')
varOutput="$varDate | $varCurlError | $varHttpCode | $varResponseTime"
echo "$varOutput"
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `wget` so you see if you can get any data and it can be simple like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S');
wget domain/yourindex
if [ -f /home/$USER/yourindex ] ; then
#echo $dt GOOD  >> /var/log/fix.log
echo GOOD >/dev/null 2>&1
else
#counter measures like sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm.service && sudo systemctl restart nginx
echo $dt BROKEN >> /var/log/fix.log
fi
rm login*
exit
```